# Read and open a .pat file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a `.pat` file and I want to know how I can open it in Matlab. I tried using `imread` and `imshow` but it says `"unable to determine file format"`. Any advice please?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer for read, trying someting with function xlsread()

Comment: Since `.pat` is a format for Photoshop pattern files, I find it surprising that `xlsread` would be able to open the file! Do you have any evidence of this?